# EDI 999 implementation acknowledgment

Tags: edi

What is the purpose of context information such as element,segment and business context in EDI 999 implementation acknowledgment?

Answer (score 0):

999 file acknowleges the number of claims received,claims accepted and rejected.that is the claim number is based on the number of CLM segments in 837 file